# Unbounded container with column widths equal to the width of the widest column

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a carousel that overflows it's container, to hide elements not yet visible, so they can be animated using CSS.

I would like each column in the carousel to be the same width (equal to the width of the widest element in the columns) regardless of the content in each individual column.

I understand flexbox can do this with `flex: 1` in each column, but only if the container has a fixed width. But, I want it to overflow. Is there a way to do this with just CSS?

```css
.container {
      position: absolute;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      /* left: -100px; */
    }
    
    .col {
      /* flex: 1; */
      flex-grow: 1;
    }

    .item {
      margin: 0.25rem;
      background-color: red;
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
    }

    .fat {
      width: 200px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="item fat"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="item fat"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="item fat"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="item fat"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="item fat"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="item fat"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS grid can do it. All you need is to set a column flow and make all the columns equal to `1fr`. Due to the width calculation of absolute element I had to add a big negative margin to allow the element to grow as much as possible.

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
  margin-right: -9999px;
}
.col {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.item {
  margin: 0.25rem;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: auto;
}

.fat {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="item fat"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="item fat"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="item fat"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="item fat"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="item fat"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="item fat"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```